# Named Entity Annotation read 'in-context' as RDF?

Tags: xml, rdf, refs, named-entity-recognition

I'm rather new to RDF, and have the basics nailed down, but I have a question about possible data sources (in addition to ontologies): is it possible to 'read' an (appropriately) Named Entity tag as an RDF subject-predicate-object(which would be the tagged text itself)... in its original context, that is to say, in its original text document?

I would not only like a query to pull a text excerpt as data itself (only linked to the original document), but allow an interface/query to include also the context in which it appeared (or: the text around it).

Comment: Possibly you could be interested in [WADM](https://www.w3.org/TR/annotation-model/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: RDFa. The ontology-source-abbreviation is declared as an 'xmlins' in the `<body>` tag of an `<html>` page, and the tags containing the text (`<span>`, `<p>`, etc.) annotated accordingly...

I was overthinking the problem while the solution was right in front of me.